# use parameter type-of id in block iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameters, block

Here is the code

```
[EvoScrollBarTagView initWithScrollView:self.listTableView
                                withTagView:[TagView new]
                                  didScroll:
                        ^(id scrollBarTagView, TagView *tagView, CGFloat offset) {

                          [scrollBarTagView showTagViewAnimation];
                          ........
```

And my confusion is why the scrollBarTagView(type-of id) can call the method or properties in my EvoScrollBarTagView.h . the parameter scrollBarTagView`s type is id, not declared as the EvoScrollBarTagView`s instance object, can someone tell me why , Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Objective-C is a dynamic language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW18):

> The id type defines a generic object pointer. It’s possible to use id
>   when declaring a variable, but you lose compile-time information about
>   the object.

So it doesn't mean that `scrollBarTagView` can call any method, all it means that it will compile successfully. If the referenced method is not implemented, the app will crash during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

That's part of the point of `id` -- dynamic typing. You can try to send any message (that the compiler knows about at this point in the code) to an expression of type `id` without any compiler error or warning.